# phpmyadmin. autologgin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadim. Is it possible to skip log in page so that it logs in automatically. I don't want use browser to remember password. I need that any user
who access web page should be able go and look at database entries.

Comment: Is this on a public facing web server, or internal?

Comment: perfect, then I have no qualms about what you're wanting to impliment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types#config

> auth_type = 'config' is the most basic authentication mode. The username and password are stored in phpMyAdmin configuration file. It is good for troubleshooting problems and single-user installations where "root" (or some similar super-user) is used for all administrative work. Config does not password protect phpMyAdmin; anyone who accesses the correct URL is logged directly in and can manipulate your server.
>
> If you use config, please also place your server behind a firewall or use your webserver's authentication (such as an Apache .htaccess file) to limit access to your data.
>
> In config.inc.php, also fill in values for user and password.

Please secure your installation accordingly